# How to add more punctuations to string.punctuation

Tags: python, regex, string

`print string.punctuation` looks like this:

```
!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~
```

I was wondering if we could add more punctuations to it such as the chinese fullstops that looks like this: "。"

What i am trying to do is:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

exclude = string.punctuation.decode("ascii") + u"。"
c = codecs.open("my_file.csv", "w", "utf-8")
my_string = "你好， 天气很好。"
#print my_string.encode('utf-8').translate({ord(p): None for p in exclude})
print >> c, my_string.encode('utf-8').translate({ord(p): None for p in exclude})
desired output: "你好， 天气很好"
```

`print >> c, my_string.encode('utf-8').translate({ord(p): None for p in exclude})` gives an error:

TypeError: expected a character buffer object

Answer (score 1):

You can add extra punctuation characters, but you'll probably want to work with Unicode rather than 8-bit characters if you're dealing with Chinese text. The punctuation in `string.puctuation` is all ASCII, so to work with it as a `unicode` string you'll need to decode it:

```
exclude = string.punctuation.decode("ascii") + u"。"
my_string = u"你好， 天气很好。"
print my_string.translate({ord(p): None for p in exclude})
```

Note that I had to do the `translate` call differently because `unicode.translate` takes different arguments than `str.translate` does. The one argument is a dictionary mapping from Unicode ordinals (integers) to characters, ordinals or (as I use in this case) `None` (to remove characters from the output).

If you're going to include Unicode string literals in your source code (like the `"。"` string), you'll need to make sure you have an appropriate encoding [declared at the top of your file](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/) in a comment:

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
```

(Or whatever actual encoding you're using in your editor.)

Comment: please see my edits. I got an error when i try to write it out to a file

Comment: I think you have some confused logic regarding which strings are unicode and which are not. you should never need to call `decode` on `my_string` at any point, it should be `unicode` always. You might have better luck using `c.write(...)` rather than `print >> c, ...` (I'm not sure how the latter works in Python 2 with unicode text and files that expect it).